# Laravel 5.1 - @include tag isn't working

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am new for laravel framework.please can you help me find good solution for this.may be this is a small thing.but i didn't tough it unfortunatly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Site</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">        </script>
      <script     src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">        </script>
    </head>
        <body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="add">New Site</button>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
  @include('newSite')
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <caption>Site Info</caption>
    <thead>
      <th>Site ID</th>
      <th>Site Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      @foreach($sites as $key => $site)
      <tr id="site{{$site->site_id}}">
        <td>{{$site->site_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$site->site_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$site->site_description}}</td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-edit">Edit</button>
          <button value="btn btn-danger btn-delete">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#add").on('click',function(){
    $('#site').modal('show');
  })
</script>


</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

this is a my site.blade.php view file.i need to include newSite.blade.php file to this file.i used @include('newSite') line.but it is not working.also when i put this command not working all below codes.please help me as soon as possible

Comment: what happen when you are calling @include('newSite') ?

Comment: my out put only show "New Site" Button.table isn't show in my out put.i want to  when click the new site button, open the newSite.blade.php as a popup

Comment: Ok, means you want to show newSite.blade.php as a popup ??

Comment: yes.i need to when click the new site button, show newSite.blade.php file as a popup

Comment: Can you share your `@include('newSite')` code. And check the model HTML code is rendering in the browser or not, you can do this by Viewing Page Source.

Comment: it is ok Sir.i done some small mistakes in newSite.blade.php page.that is the reason it is not worked.now it is ok.thank you for your kindly  prompt support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#add").on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        method : 'get',
        url    : '{{ url("/getData") }}',
        data   : 
        {
            var1 : val1
        },
        success: function(response)
        {
            $('#site').html(response);  // this response will contain the view returned from getData controller function

            // Jquery UI dialog
            $('#site').dialog({
                title   : 'Your Title',
                width   : 400,
                height  : 350,
                modal   : true,
                closeOnEscape: false
            });
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', 'black');
        }
    })
});
```